# How To: Draw (HTML5) Video into (Custom) Canvas Shape with KinecticJS

Tags: html5-canvas, html5-video

Here's my example: http://jsbin.com/urofan/7/edit

I would like to draw the video into a custom shape, not in a rectangle shape, is that possible  right now? (PS: The shape is draggable) All I found in StackO or in the web are for rectangular drawings...

In the future, the shape will be a circle with adjustable radius and position (draggable and resizable).

Thanks for your help.
Allan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can contain an image (video frame grab) into a path using the clip method.**

[image]

First define the path you want the video frame to be contained in.

Note that you don’t have to do fill/stroke.

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(200, 50);
context.lineTo(420, 80);
context.lineTo(250, 400);
context.lineTo(40, 80);
context.closePath();
```

Next, create a clipping path from your defined path.

Everything drawn after this will be clipped inside your clipping path.

```
context.clip();
```

Finally, draw a frame grab of the video and drawImage into the clipping path.

The frame grab will only appear inside your clipping path.

```
context.drawImage(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/aMW74/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    var img=document.createElement("img");
    img.onload=function(){
        drawClippedImage(img);
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/KoolAidMan.png";

    function drawPathForClipping(context){
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(200, 50);
        context.lineTo(420, 80);
        context.lineTo(250, 400);
        context.lineTo(40, 80);
        context.closePath();
    }

    function drawClippedImage(img){

        var shape = new Kinetic.Shape({
          id: 'shape',
          drawFunc: function(canvas) {
            var context = canvas.getContext();

            // define the path that will be used for clipping
            drawPathForClipping(context);

            // make the last path a clipping path
            context.clip();

            // draw a clipped image (frame grab)
            context.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);


            // styling, draw the clip path for real as a border
            drawPathForClipping(context);
            canvas.stroke(this);

          },
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 4,
          draggable: true
        });

        // add the shape shape to the layer
        layer.add(shape);
        layer.draw();

    }

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! that works great. just need context.clip() in my drawing function: http://jsbin.com/urofan/9/